# Custom Events not firing in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an aspx page `Page1.aspx` where an event is raised:

```
private void helper_Response(Results pagedResults,Wrap wrap)
{
    // Do database calls
}
```

In the same file there is a `Load()` inside it is called like this:

```
void Load()
{
    test = new Helper();
    test.responseevent += new  TestEventHandler(helper_Response);
}
```

There is a helper class created `PageHelper`:

```
public class Helper
{
     ..
     public event EventHandler responseevent;
}
```

There is a delegate as well:

```
public delegate void TestEventHandler(Results pagedResults,Wrap wrap);
```

When I am debugging `Load()`, I was expecting `helper_Response()` to be invoked, but it is not getting invoked.

What is the condition to invoke this event?

Comment: `OnLoad` only registers the eventhandler, you never call it! You have to trigger the event somewhere in your code where it makes sense, like `responseevent.invoke(...)`

Comment: or preferably: `responseevent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);`